# Redirect The Page if Anchor Text is not Match

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Javascript Expert,

i am a template developer and i used my link for credit link at the bottom in template. sometime people changed the anchor text of my site link,
and i want if someone change the **anchor text** then it should redirect to example.com

```
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
    <p>Designed by:<a href='http://www.thesofthelp.com'>the soft zone</a> 
     SEO By: <a href='http://www.mojo.com'>mojo</a>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Example** Lets suppose someone changed the **"The Soft Zone"** to **"Dream Code"** then page should redirect to example.com

```
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
    <p>Designed by:<a href='http://www.thesofthelp.com'>Dream Code</a> 
     SEO By: <a href='http://www.mojo.com'>mojo</a>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now it should be redirected to example.com because the user changed the anchor text from "The Soft Zone" to "Dream Code"

I hope someone will give the script.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No @RevanProdigalKnight please share code with me if you can, #Taplar has shared the code but that does not work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any Javascript GURU here to make this Script ? If Anchor is Changed Redirect the Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644425/any-javascript-guru-here-to-make-this-script-if-anchor-is-changed-redirect-the)

Comment: Please stop creating the same question multiple times, it pollutes the site and benefits no-one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like...

```
$(function(){
    var $link = $('#copyright a');

    (function verifyCopyright () {
        if ($link.prop('href') !== 'http://www.thesofthelp.com' || $link.text() !== '**The Soft Zone**') {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
        } else {
            setTimeout(verifyCopyright, 1000);
        }
    })();
});
```

So this would check every second to see if the text of the link changed and if so redirect.  The reason I did it this way is if the user put in a script to change it dynamically after a certain period of time, an immediate check would fail.

Here's a concern with this though.  If the users are not changing the template dynamically and are instead changing your actual script, what's to stop them from removing this verification?  It seems like any solution will be very weak.

There are also other concerns.  They could remove the element entirely.  They could hide it.  They could change it to position absolutely off the screen at -1000px.  So many ways they could jack with any kind of verification like this.

Comment: no, they cannot change the actual script, because i encrypt that actual script and then add in template.....However, i want you to edit the above script because you add #copyright a  please use like this if http://www.thesofthelp.com' anchor texts is not "the soft zone" then redirect it...you check it by "copyright a" and i want, you to add the original link in script...i hope you will do it..thanks

Comment: i used already so many script, then cannot change the css for any of those div...come to the point, No, i dont what mean, you use the OR condition and i dont mean that, i mean to not use the #copyright a in script, use the original url instead of #copyright a because #copyright a holds other url too. so the script will apply on all...i am updating the above html structure...use a condition like this. if www.thesofthelp.com anchor text is not "the soft zone" then redirect the page...or check the above structure, i am removing the other div section so you got the idea. thanks.

Comment: Please put an id/class on the link to target it.  Otherwise there is no way to know which link needs to be validated.  And then the $('#copyright a') would simply be changed to be that selector.

Comment: you check the above html structure i update it...is there not any way to target it by the original link " like this--- If (http://www.thesofhtlpe.com) anchor !== to (the soft zone) then redirect the page.

Comment: you check i update the html structure, or i must put the id/class ?

Comment: @Tapar i updated the html by adding the id..however your code is not working because inside the #copyright a there is two hfef links..your code: $(function(){
    var $link = $('#copyright a');

    (function verifyCopyright () {
        if ($link.text() !== '**The Soft Zone**') {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
        } else {
            setTimeout(verifyCopyright, 1000);
        }
    })();
});