# Any Javascript GURU here to make this Script ? If Anchor is Changed Redirect the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Javascript expert,

i used a link in my own created templates...as you see the below ones:

```
<a href='http://www.allbloggertricks.com'>Blogging Tips</a>
```

No, i want if change the **anchor text** from **Blogging Tips** to any other then the page should be redirected to example.com .

Example: if the link become like this:

```
<a href='http://www.allbloggertricks.com'>Awesome Tips</a>
```

Now the page should be redirect to example.com because its anchor text changed from **"Blogging Tips"** to

**"Awesome Tips"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect The Page if Anchor Text is not Match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642898/redirect-the-page-if-anchor-text-is-not-match)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the page to automatically redirect or to just have the URL changed dynamically.  As you used the term 'redirect' I'll go with the first one.  Run something like this once your page has loaded.

```
var anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var len = anchorTags.length;
while (len--) {
    var anchor = anchorTags[len];
    if (anchor.textContent === "Awesome Tips") {
        anchor.href = "http://example.com/";
        anchor.click();
    }
}
```

Hope that helped. :)

---

**EDIT**: Further to the comment below.

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to identify the specific anchor tag and then check to see if it's text is "Blogging Tips", or not.  The first thing to do is give your target anchor tag a unique identification (id)...

```
<a href="http://..etc.." id="the_link">Blogging Tips</a>
```

Now you can easily find it with...

```
var theLink = document.getElementById('the_link');
```

You can then do a check similar to that suggestion above, but this time to see if the text is NOT 'Blogging Tips'...

```
if (theLink.textContent !== "Blogging Tips") {
   // .... do something ...
}
```

If you want to redirect the page the easiest thing to do is use `window.location.assign`([More on this at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)).

You can only make this check once the page has loaded, so you'll need to wrap this inside a `window.onload` function or put it in a function that can be called once the page is loaded ([More on this at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)).  Assuming the first option, the JavaScript now looks like this...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var theLink = document.getElementById("the_link");
  if (theLink.textContent !== "Blogging Tips") {
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/");
  }
};
```

However, if your template user removes or changes the anchor tag's id, or changes your JavaScript there is little you can do about it.

Hope that helped a bit more.  :)

Comment: h @BrianPeacock this not what i want....listen i am creating templates and put my link this one: <a href='http://www.allbloggertricks.com'>Blogging Tips</a>
 at botoom, now when some users download the template and upload to their site, they change only the anchor texts "Blogging Tips" now how to add a script, if they change anchor texts "Blogging Tips" to any other then the page should be redirected to example.com

Comment: or look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642898/redirect-the-page-if-anchor-text-is-not-match for better understanding..you share the code in that post too.

Comment: thanks bundles, it worked for me, i just add the "the_link" id to the same ahref link which i targeted, and it worked perfect. thanks again.